# BIML never generate Package ProtectionLevel properly

Tags: bids, ssis-2012, biml

I have set my project level protection level to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and in all my packages that I generate using BIML I have code below

```xml
<Package Name ="MyPackage" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithPassword" PackagePassword="mypass">
```

For some reason I have to set ProtectionLevel to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword manually after every time I generate package using BIDS Helper. This is a painful job. I have no clue why should not work. Any clues?

I am using 1.7.0 version of BIDSHelper downloaded from Codeplex and SQL Server Data Tools version 2012 (as you might already know the confusing part is that VS version is 2010)

**Update:**
Below is the new structure of biml recommended by iamdave which is not generating any ouput in the ProjectSubPath and the ExceptionDataMigrator package is still generating witth default packlage protection

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Projects>
        <PackageProject ProjectSubpath="bimlOutput"
                Name = "Solution/Project"
                ProtectionLevel = "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword"
                ProjectPassword = "password"
                >
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter Name="sTestParam" DataType="String">This is project parameter</Parameter>
            </Parameters>
            <Packages>
                <Package PackageName="ExceptionDataMigrator">

                </Package>
            </Packages>

        </PackageProject>
    </Projects>
    <Connections>
        <Connection Name="Staging" CreateInProject="true" ConnectionString="Data Source=b.database.windows.net;User ID=h;Initial Catalog=Migration_Staging;Password=z;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Auto Translate=False;" RetainSameConnection="true" />
        <Connection Name="Reporting" CreateInProject="true" ConnectionString="Data Source=Dev2;Initial Catalog=ng;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;" RetainSameConnection="true" />
        <Connection Name="SalesForceDB" CreateInProject="true" ConnectionString="Data Source=db;Initial Catalog=SalesForce;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=false;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>

    <Package Name="ExceptionDataMigrator" ConstraintMode="Linear" ProtectionLevel="EncryptSensitiveWithPassword" PackagePassword="password">
        <Parameters>
```

Comment: Are you using the package deployment level or project deployment level? I don't have an instance with bids helper running, but I can confirm that [Biml Express](http://www.varigence.com/BimlExpress), also free, will correctly emit a package with the proper protection level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating the packages in the same VS project as your BIML files or as a whole new solution?  If I remember correctly I had a similar problem and resolved it by specifying a `ProjectSubPath` within the `<PackageProject>` node of `<Projects>`, as the packages being created within my BIML project were inheriting the protection level of the BIML project:

```
<Projects>
    <PackageProject
            ProjectSubPath = "Folder to save new solution"
            Name = "Solution/Project Name"
            ProtectionLevel = "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword"
            ProjectPassword = "Password"
            >
        <Parameters>
            <!-- Add Parameters here -->
        </Parameters>
        <Packages>
            <Package PackageName = "Package 1" />
        </Packages>
    </PackageProject>
</Projects>
```

Be **VERY CAREFUL** where you point that `ProjectSubPath` as it will completely delete any folder that already exists at that address, regardless of what it contains, then recreate it and create your new solution within.

Comment: This is interesting. I am creating only Package from within existing solution/project.

Comment: @SolowDeveloper then the package you create will inherit the protection level of the solution.  Change it there and your newly created packages will have the right protection level.

Comment: can you please check my edited OP, I don't think i fully understand the hierarchy. I have crated bimlOutput folder within my package folder, it did not generate anything in that folder nor the package generated in same folder has expected proection level

Comment: @SolowDeveloper  Your `ProjectSubPath` is not relative, it needs to start from the root drive of your desired folder structure and include a trailing space eg: `C:\Folder 1\Folder 2\Target Folder\"

Comment: Thanks it created the project but there is no solution file created. Is there any resource/link available for detailed usage of <Projects> element?

Comment: @SolowDeveloper  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141695.aspx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122220/discussion-between-solow-developer-and-iamdave).